# QGIS2THREEJS Installation Windows Problem

Tags: qgis2threejs

I just install qgis2threejs on the plugin (i use qgis 3.4.3 madeira) but I can't activate and I get caution about this. I try to reinstall qgis but it didn't work. after i click ok then qgis close automatically. anyone can help me?[image]

Comment: The error is for `Coordinate capture` plugin not Qgis2threejs. You cannot uninstall core plugin which comes with QGIS software.

Comment: Your screenshot you provided is missleading, since it shows the Coordinate Capture plugin and it is not clear if the error is from qgis2threejs. Please provide a clearer screenshot

Comment: so what should I do to activating qgisthreejs without any problem of this